# How to plot a graph of Linkage disequilibrium with limited information

Tags: snp, haplotypes, graphs

I have a snp information in an excel file and I used SNPstat to do some analysis. But I also need a plot of LD for these snps. But my file is not formatted as the most programs required (.ped, hapmap, Plink...). Here is a screen shot of file: [image: Data file]

I have also chromosome numbers and rs information for this snps. Due to this data format problem I couldn't use Haploview or other programs. Can you suggest me a solution to create a LD graph?

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/28/19/2537/288671

Comment: you need an LD matrix, which your table is not.  The LD matrix is a pairwise matrix.  See this page for an example: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gaston/versions/1.4.9/topics/LD.plot